# Jwplayer does not work on Safari

Tags: safari, jwplayer

Jwplayer does not work on Safari `(player version 7.2.2 with updated flash in browser - tested on windows 8.1 & 10)`. This is the case even on their own web site (https://dashboard.jwplayer.com/#/players/basic_setup

you have to be logged in to access page).

The error message is `Failed to setup Flash JSON`.

stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures.

`Can someone who has an upgraded account request support from jwplayer?`

They do not accept questions from non-paying accounts. Do they intend to correct this? Why does Safari setup flash and not use html5?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It could be any number of things going wrong, and it's always best to provide a fiddle to allow for a quick diagnosid. Let's help you get squared away with the new JW Player 7. You can instantiate the player using the html5 player in this fashion, but JW Player does now use the HTML5 player by default in version 7.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">jwplayer.key="YOURJWKEY"</script>

<div id="thePlayer"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
       jwplayer("thePlayer").setup({
           file: "file.mp4",
           width:640,
           height:360,
           primary: "html5"
       });
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug which was introduced with JW 7.2.0 and has been fixed in JW 7.2.4 (currently in beta).